# Unable to execute JSTL XML ForEach statements

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I am new to J2EE. I have created the Dynamic web project and created JSP files to use the JSTL XML tags to parse simple xml and reading the nodes using forEach loop. I am using Tomcat 9 version.
I have copied the JSTL-1.2 into WEB-INF/LIB folder and JSTL Core/Function/XML tags are recognized in my JSP code however when i coded JSTL XML forEach functionality then i started getting error.

I added the servlet-api.jar, jsp-api.jar from Tomcat 9 as part of build path.

JSP code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>  
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>  
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>XML Parse and forEach</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:import url="/Users.xml" var="XMLFile"/> 
    <x:parse xml="${XMLFile }" var="XMLdoc"/>

    <x:forEach var="usr" select="$XMLdoc/users/user">
        <x:out select="name"/>
        <x:out select="gender"/>
        <x:out select="age"/>
    </x:forEach>
    
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing [XMLForEach.jsp] at line [17]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [XMLForEach.jsp] at line [17]

14:     <c:import url="/Users.xml" var="XMLFile"/> 
15:     <x:parse xml="${XMLFile }" var="XMLdoc"/>
16: 
17:     <x:forEach var="usr" select="$XMLdoc/users/user">
18:         <x:out select="name"/>
19:         <x:out select="gender"/>
20:         <x:out select="age"/>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:610)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:499)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Root Cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UnSupported Return Type : {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}OBJECT
    java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImplUtil.isSupported(XPathImplUtil.java:248)
    java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:127)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.XPathUtil.selectNodes(XPathUtil.java:258)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ForEachTag.prepare(ForEachTag.java:59)
    javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
    org.apache.jsp.XMLForEach_jsp._jspx_meth_x_005fforEach_005f0(XMLForEach_jsp.java:261)
    org.apache.jsp.XMLForEach_jsp._jspService(XMLForEach_jsp.java:159)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.


Apache Tomcat/9.0.48

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jul 04, 2021 2:02:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/S08LAL_-_JSTLXMLTags] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [XMLForEach.jsp] at line [17]

14:     <c:import url="/Users.xml" var="XMLFile"/> 
15:     <x:parse xml="${XMLFile }" var="XMLdoc"/>
16: 
17:     <x:forEach var="usr" select="$XMLdoc/users/user">
18:         <x:out select="name"/>
19:         <x:out select="gender"/>
20:         <x:out select="age"/>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UnSupported Return Type : {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}OBJECT
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImplUtil.isSupported(XPathImplUtil.java:248)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:127)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.XPathUtil.selectNodes(XPathUtil.java:258)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ForEachTag.prepare(ForEachTag.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
    at org.apache.jsp.XMLForEach_jsp._jspx_meth_x_005fforEach_005f0(XMLForEach_jsp.java:261)
    at org.apache.jsp.XMLForEach_jsp._jspService(XMLForEach_jsp.java:159)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)


[Build path][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCSzu.png
```

Comment: I have strong suspicion that you are running tomcat 9 on Java 16? is this correct? If you try to run Tomcat 9 on Java 15 will the error still happen?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve this problem.

The possible cause is that you are running your app with old jstl libraries on Tomcat 9 with Java 16. It is interesting that that old libraries are perfectly good for Tomcat 9 with Java 15. But not with Java 16! Perhaps something was changed in Java 16 about XPath support.

Your exception may look like this:

```
08-Sep-2021 20:43:34.213 SEVERE [http-nio-8888-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UnSupported Return Type : {http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}OBJECT
        at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:276)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.XPathUtil.selectNodes(XPathUtil.java:258)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ForEachTag.prepare(ForEachTag.java:59)
        at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
```

**First**: download new jstl libraries from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-taglibs.cgi

**Second**: download dependencies listed here: https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/taglibs/taglibs-standard-1.2.5/README_bin.txt

- xalan-2.7.1.jar
- serializer-2.7.1.jar

**Third**: make sure you do not have old jstl and standard jar files in Tomcat classpath or in your web app class path.

Tested with

- apache-tomcat-9.0.52: Server version name: Apache Tomcat/9.0.52
- Java 16.0.2: JVM Version: 16.0.2+7-67